# How, in Access VBA, do you open a filtered form in DataSheet mode?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I'm sure I've encountered this before and can't remember if I ever found a way around it.  I need to open a modal, filtered form in DataSheet mode.  I've set the default and only allowed mode as DataSheet, but when I

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmOptyFeedbackExport", acNormal, , , acFormReadOnly, acDialog
```

It comes up as single form, anyone know why and how to force it to open as datasheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want acNormal:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmOptyFeedbackExport",acFormDS, , , acFormReadOnly, acDialog
```

I would be pretty careful about modal forms.

Comment: Thanks, why would you be careful?

Comment: Bitter experience. They can interfere horribly with something you want to do next, so I only use them when I must.

Comment: I basically never use Dialog/Modal forms. Use them the same as you would a message box. Try setting the form's Popup property to True instead (leave modal false).